# Search view can't expanded programmatically in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I try to expand and focus the search view programmatically in Fragment. But it was not expanded. I refer the internet and try so many time But it was not expanded. But same time searchView expanded in activity. below code was I used.

```
@Override
       public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     SearchView searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search);
     searchView.setIconified(true);
     searchView.requestFocus();
}
```

I expect Once I show the fragment, That fragment's search view should be focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand your `SearchView` with `setIconified` set to false

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

And collapsed with true

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried both but not working in the fragment.